# Filtering a reverse relationship by user, and returning only one object in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Given these models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=255)

class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

A user can only have a single Order object per product. I would like an API call to show a list of products, with the user's order where available. Is there a way to do that?

The default serialisation lists ALL orders under `order_set`. I did get a bit ahead with this to filter by user:

```
class FilteredOrderSerializer(serialisers.ListSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, data):
        data = data.filter(user=self.context['request'].user)
        return super(FilteredOrderSerializer, self).to_representation(data)


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        list_serializer_class = FilteredOrderSerializer


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    order_set = OrderSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
```

So now it only shows the authenticated user's order, but the resulting JSON looks something like

```
[
    {
        "name": "prod1",
        "order_set": [
            {
                "quantity": 4
            }
        ],
    }
]
```

i.e. the field is still called `order_set` and it's a list, while I would like it to be called `order` and be either an object or null. So I'm not sure where this filtering should take place, nor how to define the field.

Edit: I'm using a simple viewset

```
class ProductViewSet(view sets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
```

Comment: Will need some details around your view for the same.

Comment: Added viewset above

Comment: How does your ProductSerializer Look ? Fix is there only.

Comment: Was just adding the ProductSerializer as well, it's there now ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add related_name field in your orders so you can

```
product.orders.all()
```

Then this should do.

```
class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='orders')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    order = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('name', 'order')

    def get_order(self, object):
        try:
            order = object.orders.get(user=self.context['request'].user)
            return SceneDetailSerializer(order).data
        except Order.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Update: You can try out serializer method field. Not sure if self contains context and user references in it. You need to remove listfield from your order serializer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: This will still return a list though, that's my main issue. I know there will be one or none orders per user per product, so I want to return a single order or null. Whether it's called `order_set` or `orders` is not important. (`order` would be better)

Comment: That kind of works! I had to `return OrderSerializer(order).data`, and I get the JSON I'm looking for. Unfortunately, SerializerMethodFields are read only, but I'm trying to find a way around that.